# Reposition the words enclosed in [ ] in a sentence using R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, reorderlist

```
[VN] [Ren'Py] Game1 [Author1]

[VN] [Ren'Py] Game2 [Author2]

[VN] [Ren'Py] Game3 [Author3]
```

I have these 3 lines saved in a text file. I want to rearrange them in such a way that my **output** looks like:

```
Game1 [Author1] [VN] [Ren'Py]

Game2 [Author2] [VN] [Ren'Py]

Game3 [Author3] [VN] [Ren'Py]
```

When I first read the text file into RStudio, it creates a dataframe with 1 variable and the class of all the game names are as character.

```
a = read.csv("games.txt")
```

I then use grepl to exract all the names that contain [ ]

```
b = a$name[grepl("\\[.*", a$name)]
```

Here again I face an issue. I actually only want to grepl those names that start with [

```
b = a$name[grepl("^\\[.*", a$name)]
```

But using the caret does not work. Doing so gives me a dataframe of 0 columns and 3 rows

Now, b is a character of length 3 and running

```
b[1]
b[2]
b[3]
```

gives me the entire name of each game respectively

I then run strsplit to separate the words of the games by the spaces

```
c = strsplit(b, " +")
```

Now c is of class "list" of length 3

I then tried to run this code

```
seq = 1 : length(c)
y = NULL
for (i in seq){
  tmp <- c[[i]][1]
  y[i] = tmp
  c[[i]][-1]
}
```

This ideally should have extracted [VN] from c[[1]] , stored it in y[1] and then removed [VN] from c[[1]].

However, y gets rewritten everytime and when the loop completes only c[[3]][1] is stored in y.

I am now stuck here and have very little idea about how I can proceed to get my output. Please advise

Comment: use `write.table(read.table("games.txt")[c(3,4,1,2)],"games1.txt",row.names =  FALSE)`

Comment: My actual games list has lines with different number of elements so read.table was causing an error — "Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 7 elements"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Data:

```
x <- c("[VN] [Ren'Py] Game1 [Author1]")
```

Solution:

```
sub("(\\[[^[]+) (\\[[^[]+) (\\w+) (\\[[^[]+)", "\\3 \\1 \\2 \\4", x)
```

Result:

```
[1] "Game1 [VN] [Ren'Py] [Author1]"
```

Comment: Thank you, my actual list contains names with different lengths ie. some are "game name 1 game name 2 ...." and "game name 1 game name 2 game name 3...", however I think I should be able to generalize the solution to fit for different lengths. Thank you

Comment: If my answer helped answer your question or was useful to answering it, please consider accepting the answer and/or upvoting it (see left upper margin of answer)

Comment: Thank you, can you also provide some advice on the loop part of my question? I wanted y to be a list or a dataframe. However, the y values were simply being overwritten and not being added/pasted after every loop